# Is there a way to use the new Linq to Xml classes but still validate the XML file against a schema file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Bit stuck trying to use the new lightweight Linq/XML classes in .NET.  I can find 'old' code that uses the System.Xml.XmlReader and will load an XML file and allow validation against an XSD schema file, but I can't find any code that shows how to get the newer Linq/XML classes to do the same validation.  Seem to be missing a key Lego brick here somewhere.

Comment: There is [`XDocument.Validate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method available. You should try it.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Validate Using XSD (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx) on MSDN.